# style-loader failing in React SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-style-loader

Created reusable react library, currently it is working only in client side. If I try to run in server side, it will throw the below error because of `style-loader`. Basically I want to bundle both css and js into single file(UMD). So that it will be easy for the consumer. Is that possible? I thought about styled-component and emotion js, but not sure whether it will create any other dependency in the main app. Looking for better option to bundle it.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at t (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:1925)
at B (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:2013)
at A.exports (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:5558)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:990)
at s (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:62)
at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:14364)
at s (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:62)
at /Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:861
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/srisukum/Documents/dev/react-library/react-reusable-lib/build/index.js:1:870)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
filename: "index.js",
libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
module: {
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build|dist)/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
  }
]
},
optimization: {
 minimizer: [
  new UglifyJsPlugin({
    cache: false,
    parallel: true,
    uglifyOptions: {
      compress: true,
      ecma: 6,
      mangle: true
    }
  })
 ]
},
externals: {
  'react': 'commonjs react'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [isomorphic-style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader) in SSR.